# What Xcode version do I need to compile for armv7s?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an iPhone 5c. How can I compile an Xcode project for armv7s architecture? I downloaded Xcode 9.2 but the only architecture I can find in the Project Configuration screen is arm64.

So, how do you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 5c is 32-bit and will not accept any system later than iOS 10.x. Therefore, to compile for it, you must set the deployment target to iOS 10. When you do, you'll get a binary that includes 32-bit. You can do that even with Xcode 10.

[image]

Comment: I mean, the Project Settings only has arm64 in supported architectures

Comment: I have already selected iOS target to 10.3 , but in supported architrectures I can only see arm64 option

Comment: Well, I don't have these options that you have. Also, in SDK folder (under /Developer.... path) I only have iOS 11.

Answer (score 0):

try to edit "Valid Architectures" section with double click of the value part, just type armv7 armv7s with space among each architecture.